# Pygame: Other way of checking mouse button up

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game via a game class setup like this:

```
class Game:
   def __init__(self)

   def new(self)
       run()

   def events(self)

   def update(self)

   def draw(self)

   def run(self)
       while True:
           events()
           update()
           draw()

g = Game()
while g.isrunning:
    g.new()
```

Rough sketch of the template. Also probably need to tell I'm working with sprites, created from another class.

I first wanted a sprite to be removed when you click on it so in the update function i checked:

```
self.mouseState = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if (sprite.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and self.mouseState[0]):
    sprite.kill()
```

this works and made me happy. But now i want it to happen when you RELEASE the mousebutton. I know you can check MOUSEBUTTONUP in the events function via "for event in pygame.event.get():" but with the way my template works i can't call that in the game loop (the update function) right?

Comment: you have to remember previous `get_pressed()` to compare with current `get_pressed()` - if it changed from `True` to `False` then button was released. Or you have to remeber MOUSEBUTTONUP as global value and check in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over the sprite group if a `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event appears and then kill the sprite if it collides with the `event.pos` or `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`.

```
import pygame as pg


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue2'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group(Player((200, 200)), Player((400, 200)))
        self.done = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic()
            self.draw()
            self.clock.tick(30)

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if event.button == 1:  # Left mouse button.
                    for sprite in self.all_sprites:
                        if sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                            sprite.kill()

    def run_logic(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    Game().run()
    pg.quit()
```